# Informing the application that the user Clear'ed one of the application's status bar notification

Tags: android, events, notifications, statusbar

when the user opens/looks at the status bar notifications and clicks Clear (which clears all the status bar notifications)
does the service that created one of the cleared status bar notification gets informed about it and if so, how?
otherwise, how can the application know that the user has Clear'ed one of the application's status bar notification? (i think i read somewhere that there is a way to poll the status of a notification, but i prefer not to poll it but instead to be informed when it's Clear'ed)

Answer (score 1):

When using a service, probably it's better to use a single notification, and set its flag as

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | 
    Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
```

so it will be in the ongoing notification group, and won't be clearable. This way you can manage when and what to show, when to hide, etc. Also, due to this, gc won't be called over your service's resources.

Comment: is there a method i can use for this in case one day someone will try to fix this problem of broken encapsulation of Notification?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You can create a `setupNotification` method, and among other basic settings can set this one too. I hope I didn't get your question wrong.

Comment: 1) that's ok. it just that flags should not be public - it's bad design (broken encapsulation) and i'd rather not manipulate it directly in my code but i guess there is no other choice   2) i didn't really get an answer to my question yet. but you provided me with a good temporary solution until i do get an answer (i don't mind that the user Clear's my appl notification as long as my code gets notified of that)  3) thanks for your reply. i'll credit you for that :-)